# SQL skip or ignore a specific cells

Tags: sql, cell

I need to develop an SQL command that will skip/ignore or possibly change/modify specific cells that contain all 9's. The tables run automatically and go through each field (6 total) and the system needs to know to skip those cells that contain all 9's and NOT skip the entire row or column.

Comment: Do you know the number of 9's?  What do you want it to do, if it's "skipping" a cell but not the entire row -- make it null? If it's a definitive amount of 9's and the result should be NULL, then: `NULLIFF(Column, 999)` or if it should be something else: `ISNULL(NULLIF(Column, 999), Value it should be'`

Comment: it's 10 9's, like a phone number '9999999999' and changing it to a null value or deleting the 9's would be fine.  I just want to do something to that cell and NOT the entire row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the count of 9's in the column is always 10, you can change the value to NULL using the NULLIF function.

```
SELECT NULLIF(Column1, 999999999), 
       NULLIF(Column2, 999999999), 
       NULLIF(Column3, 999999999)
FROM Table
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that would work on a system that functions properly.  I appreciate your help!